# How to write XML to CSV format

Tags: php, php-7.1

I am working on a simple console program that parse RSS to .csv format, but i am stuck on foreach loop. I need to write every tag to the file separated by commas, but it just finds the first ones and store it as an object, so it prevents me to write it to the file.

Everything works fine until this foreach loop. Program gets a RSS link from command line and creates an array with the whole content. I can access it and print on the console, but the foreach loop can only output the first iteration.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->children() as $item) {
    echo $item->item->title, ",";
    echo $item->item->description, ",";
    echo $item->item->link, ",";
    echo $item->item->pubDate, ",";
    echo $item->item->author, ",";    
}
```

The XML file looks like this:

```
<item>
  <title></title>
  <description></description>
  <author></author>
  <link></link>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
</item>
```

And the output of $item while using return_r is:

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [title] => 
                [description] => 
                [author] => 
                [link] =>  
                [pubDate] => 
            )
```

But when i am trying to echo $item->item->title it just gives me the content from only one iteration.

Comment: You should add a sample of the XML you are parsing and the result it is actually giving, it might make it easier for people to help you. Also, you should echo a "\n" before the closing tag on your foreach, otherwise your results will all be on one line (could that even be your current problem?).

Comment: I have added how the xml and output in console looks a like.

Comment: _“The XML file looks like this:”_ - with `item` being the root element? Then you would not have multiple items to loop over in the first place. Assuming you actually mean multiple such items as children of a different root element, then you simply have one `item` too many in your path you want to access. You want `$item->title` etc.

Comment: Writing CSV “manually” is not recommendable btw. You should gather your data for one row in an array, and use `fputcsv`.

Comment: Thanks for replies, misorude you are right, i needed to put this into an array and use fputcsv. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself. Working code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {

    $title = $item->title;
    $desc = $item->description;
    $link = $item->link;
    $pub = $item->pubDate;
    $author = $item->author;

    $fields = array($title, $desc, $link, $pub, $author);

    fputcsv($file, $fields);
}
```